# Verifying two form fields by comparing them in an constraint

Tags: forms, validation, scala, playframework, constraints

I'm currently fighting with Scala constraints.
I have a case class to bind the form to and a mapping function.

But i don't know how to verify two fields by comparing them (the first should be greater than the second)

Currently I'm thinking it should be done like this:

**models/JobRequest.scala**

```
package models

case class AddJobRequest (
    exrange: Boolean, 
    exrangefrom: Int,
    exrangeto: Int
)
```

**controllers/Index.scala**

```
package controllers

/* Code code code */

val jobAddForm = Form(
mapping(
  "exrange" -> boolean,
   tuple(
    "exrangefrom" -> number(min = 7, max=19),
    "exrangeto" -> number(min  = 8, max = 20)
   ).verifying("Start number is greater than the stop number!", /** MAGIC GOES HERE */)
  )(AddJobRequest.apply)(AddJobRequest.unapply))
```

Is there are a possibility to check, if `exrangefrom` is greater than `exrangeto`? Or is that a completely bad way to check that using ad-hoc constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `verifying` on the `mapping(...)` object ! In your case, comparing `exrangefrom` and `exrangeto` could be done this way :

```
package controllers

/* Code code code */

val jobAddForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "exrange" -> boolean,
    "exrangefrom" -> number(min = 7, max=19),
    "exrangeto" -> number(min  = 8, max = 20)
  )(AddJobRequest.apply)(AddJobRequest.unapply)
  verifying(
    "Start number is greater than the stop number!",
    addJobRequest => addJobRequest.exrangefrom < addJobRequest.exrangeto
  )
)
```

Hope it's what you expected ;)

Comment: Yep thank you :)

I thought that there is kind of solution like yours, but I tried to do verifying directly in the mapping object, and not after mapping. Well, if it works -> its great! 

Which difference (maybe in the logic or performance) would be, if I would verify the fields in the mapping object? Would it be faster (because of instant error returning while it maps the fields)?

Thank you ;)

Comment: I'm not really sure that you will decrease your performance by calling  `verifying` on the `mapping` object instead of individually on each field : yes, the method `apply` of your object is called, but the `verifying` method is called only once. Still, if you need to verify a field with constraints that only concern it (and not many fields), call the `verifying` method on each field that you want to check ;) The `verifying` method should be called on the `mapping` object only when you need to compare multiple fields.